# Excel Functions

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I use this formula to track a recall list; It will tell me if a tool is due,(within a number of days),overdue,or OK. Works fine but I would like to add a "Not Required" if the due date cell,(K3), is left blank.

=IF(2*(K3(K3>=$L$2)=0,“OK”, 
IF(2(K3=$L$2)=1,“DUE”,“OVERDUE”))

Comment: The answers do the job, but I'd use the ISBLANK function instead of K3="".

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest simply:

```
=IF(K3="","Not Required", IF(2*(K3(K3>=$L$2)=0,“OK”, IF(2(K3=$L$2)=1,“DUE”,“OVERDUE”)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the whole line in another if statement:

```
=IF(K3="", "Not Required", <<Your if here>>)
```